# Xamarin Forms - iOS Input fields does not adjust position automatically as keyboard appears with contents inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview, keyboard-events

I am developing a Xamarin Forms in which I have a input entry section to end of the page.

My Layout is like the following,

```
<ScrollView>
   <StackLayout>     
          <Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Grid>
          </Grid>

          <StackLayout>
             <Entry/>
             <Entry/>
             <Entry/>
             <Editor/>
          </StackLayout>
   <StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have done scroll adjustment when the Entry/Editor Fields come to Focus. However, the entry fields are not completely getting visible as the Keyboard overlays. In Android it is working fine, but not in iOS.

If the user manually scrolls down, it is fine. How can I animate the scroll automatically to show the Entry/Editor fields in position as the Keyboard gets visible?

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could install [Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager) from Nuget on your iOS project.
Then enable it in the **AppDelegate**:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

  IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.Enable = true;

  LoadApplication(new App());

  return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```